# C# check process and change label color

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#.

I want to change the label color in a form application.

I need it without a button or anything like something.

I have a second app. When the second app is running, the label color will be green. Other times it will be red.

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("myapp");

if (processes.Length > 0)
{
    label2.ForeColor = Color.Green;
}
```

Where should I add this code?

Is there a tool for that? Like a basic work area (I am almost working on the console side because of that. I do not know form tools.)

Comment: You would probably put this piece of code in a timer tick event handler.

Comment: What is the context? What kind of form application? For what? Desktop? Web? [Windows Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms)? [ASP.NET MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC)? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably put this piece of code in a timer tick event handler.

Below is an implementation, which is tested by observing Chrome browser.

Please note that, you should also change to label ForeColor to something else when the exe is not running.

This code will check the executable per second.

Hope this helps.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer watchDogTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        watchDogTimer.Interval = 1000;
        watchDogTimer.Tick += watchDogTimer_Tick;
        watchDogTimer.Start();
    }

    void watchDogTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");

        if (processes.Length > 0)
        {
            label2.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            label2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Teşekkürler ^^ ilgin ve bilgin için iyi günler ^^